# With a constant-current, constant-voltage power supply, does the total length of the wire affect the heat produced per metre?

Tags: power-dissipation

This seems like it should be obvious, but I can't seem to get my head around it.

If I have a length of wire 7 metres long and it has a total resistance across its whole length of 2 ohms, and I connect it across the terminals of a CC/CV power supply limited to 3A at 5V, then the wire would have to dissipate ~15W of power as heat. That would be ~2.14W/metre. If I now cut the wire in half and connect it to the same power supply, does that mean the wire would dissipate the same power but across half the length and therefore focus the heat into a smaller area? I calculate that it would then be producing ~4.29W/metre of heat.

If I'm understanding this correctly, with this setup, the resistance of the wire should have no effect on heat dissipation as long as it's low enough that the current flow is being limited by the power supply, right?

In case this is an XY question, I'm considering how I might create heated clothing. I want to avoid the possibility that if some insulation breaks and the wire shorts on itself that it might suddenly get hot enough to burn me or catch fire.

In this example case the power supply would be running in CV mode. I now realise that in the real world it's running in CC due to different values.

Comment: But a 5V over 2 ohms of resistance is only 2.5 amps, which is less than 3A CC limit, so the supply works in 5V CV mode.

Comment: You have to treat the CC and CV regions separately. First compute the load resistance (R=5V/3A) at the CC/CV point ,and the length of wire that corresponds to that. Away from that point the PSU is in CC or CV; use the wire length to determine which.

Comment: @Justme Yeah that's true. I'm not sure what I was thinking when I picked those values. They were intended to be a simplification of the real setup but ended up just being wrong. Oh well, I got my answer anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends if you power supply is operating in constant voltage or constant current mode.

\$P = V^2/R\$ or equivalently \$I^2R\$ and \$R = L\rho\$ where \$\rho\$ is the resistance per length of the wire and \$L\$ is the length of the wire.

In constant voltage mode, for power per length we have \$P/L = V^2/(L\rho)/L = V^2/(L^2\rho)\$ which is not independent of \$L\$.

In constant current mode, \$P/L = I^2\cdot L\rho/L = I^2\rho\$ which is independent of \$L\$.

Comment: Great point. It would be in CC mode.

Comment: Actually in my simplified example figures it would be in CV mode, but in my real-world setup it would be in CC mode, so your last equation should be relevant. I'm confused, though, and I don't really understand the equation. How did you arrive at that? Surely if the current flow is 3A regardless of wire length, and voltage is always 5V, then the power dissipated must be 15W regardless of wire length (ignoring that at some point the wire resistance would be higher than the CC limit). How else can it work?

Comment: Ah, but in CC mode the voltage will lower to achieve that current! I see. I wonder are there CC power supplies that increase resistance rather than decrease voltage to maintain the current.

Comment: Exactly - in CC mode the voltage changes to keep the current constant. Actually, increasing resistance (inside the power supply) and decreasing output voltage are effectively the same thing from the point of view of the load.

Answer (score 3):

BTW CC & CV is an XOR condition.

1st CASE: 5V/2ohms = 2.5A , 12.5W / 7m = 1.786 W/m

2nd CASE: 3.5m = 1 ohm * 3A CC = 3V, 9W / 3.5m = 2.57 W/m

If you wanted constant W/m & temperature rise, then you would use 2.5A CC in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

> Then the wire would have to dissipate ~15W of power as heat

It doesn't *have* to.
A constant voltage / constant current power supply doesn't work in the CV / CC mode simultaneously. It is either in Cv mode or in CC mode.
So the calculation of 15W is not correct.

So, it is either 3^2 * 2 = 18W or 5^2/2 = 12.5 W dissipation in the 2 ohm case.

Since 3A*2ohm > 5V and since 5V/2ohm < 3 A, it is working in Cv mode. so 12.5 W disspation.

Comment: This would be better suited as a comment, but it's a good point.

Comment: The models I have seen has an LED or some other type of indication which indicates if the supply is working in CV mode or CC mode.

Comment: @Clonkex why would this be better as a comment? It tells you about your misunderstanding ie cc or cv but not both...

Comment: @SolarMike At the time of writing, this answer was much simpler. But either way, it doesn't attempt to answer the question. The exact numbers are not important, they were only there to illustrate the point.

Comment: The answer was being built upon an initial draft. I know that I hadn't (haven't) answered the wire cutting part of the question. I felt that any answer would have to deal with the 15W calculation from OP.

Answer (score 1):

A CV-CC power supply operates in one or the other mode, it's physically impossible for it to operate in both.

If you know the resistance of the load, calculate what the V and I would be in each mode, and then reject the one that's being exceeded.

For instance, a 2 Ω load on a 5 V 3 A power supply would give you 2.5 A at 5 V, and 6 V at 3 A. The 6 V exceeds the 5 V limit, so we know it's operating in CV mode at 5 V 2.5 A. It's dissipating 12.5 Watts.

If you now cut the wire in half, to get a 1 Ω load, you would get 5 A at 5 V, but only 3 V at 3 A. The supply has switched into CC mode, and you're dissipating 9 Watts in the wire. The wire is running at a slightly higher current, so is dissipating a little more heat per unit length.

If you are making heated clothing, and want to guard against such shorts, then you should drive the wire in CC mode.

Answer (score 1):

> If I have a length of wire 7 metres long and it has a total resistance across its whole length of 2 ohms, and I connect it across the terminals of a CC/CV power supply limited to 3A at 5V, ...

[image]

*Figure 1. The 3 A, 5 V power supply can operate at any voltage and current combination inside the shaded area. A 2 Ω wire has a voltage drop of 2 V/A.*

> ... then the wire would have to dissipate ~15W of power as heat.

No. You can see from the graph that the load-line intersects the PSU operating boundary at 5 V, 2.5 A. That gives power dissipation as 5 × 2.5 = 12.5 W. You can't drive 3 A into a 2 Ω load if the voltage is constrained to 5  V.

> That would be ~2.14W/metre.

No, it's 12.5 / 7 = 1.79 W/m.

> If I now cut the wire in half and connect it to the same power supply, ...

That gives you 1 Ω and we can see that this crosses the PSU operating boundary at 3 V, 3 A.

> ... does that mean the wire would dissipate the same power ...

No, 3 V × 3 A = 9 W.

> ... but across half the length and therefore focus the heat into a smaller area?

Into a smaller length or volume, but not area.

> I calculate that it would then be producing ~4.29W/metre of heat.

Power per unit length would be 9 W / 3.5 m = 2.57 W/m.

> ... the resistance of the wire should have no effect on heat dissipation as long as it's low enough that the current flow is being limited by the power supply, right?

As demonstrated above, this is false.

> In case this is an XY question, I'm considering how I might create heated clothing. I want to avoid the possibility that if some insulation breaks and the wire shorts on itself that it might suddenly get hot enough to burn me or catch fire.

Then use constant current mode. This will limit the power per unit length.

---

Note from Figure 1 that the maximum power that can be drawn from the PSU is when the load line passes through the top right corner. This would be 5 V / 3 A = 5/3 = 1.67 Ω.

Answer (score 0):

No, case 1 cable has 2 ohms and 5 V from you PS 5V / 2 ohm is 2.5 A. There is no limit to the current. The power output is therefore U ^ 2 / R = 25 V ^ 2/2 ohm = 12.5 W.

Case 2: Half of your cable (1 ohm): 5 V / 1 A is 5 A, but there is a limit of 3 A which means your power dissipation is I<sup>2</sup>R = 9<sup>2</sup> × 1 = 9 W.

First you have to decide what is limited and therefore known and then choose the appropriate formula.